# xUnit does not produce results file with lots of tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

### Issue

When I run xUnit tests on a project containing a lot of tests, it does not produce the xml result file.  If I reduce the number of tests in the same project to a smaller set of tests it does produce the result file.  Why is this happening?

### Details

My project has about 3200 xUnit tests running in a Jenkins build.  I am using the following command to run the tests.

```
dotnet test --logger:"xunit;LogFilePath=/results/integrationtest_results.xml"
```

However, this is not creating the integrationtest_results.xml file.  I have confirmed the tests did run even though it did not produce the result file.

When I use the following command to filter down the tests to less than 1000 tests it DOES create the integrationtest_results.xml result file.

```
dotnet test --logger:"xunit;LogFilePath=/results/integrationtest_results.xml" --filter:"someAttribute=someValue"
```

In the same Jenkins build, I have another project that runs 500 unit tests with the following command.

```
dotnet test --logger:"xunit;LogFilePath=/results/unittest_results.xml"
```

This has always produced the expected unittest_results.xml.

In the cases where it does not produce the result file, I do not see any logs stating an error occurred relating to the xunit results file.

### Environment

- C# dotnet core 6.0
- Xunit v2.4.1
- Test logger: XunitXml.TestLogger v3.0.70

Comment: Did you manage to find out why it's happening? We have the same behaviour SOMETIMES (with Nunit), but can't work out in what conditions it's happening - really frustrating!